# Azure VM update management Non-Compliant VMs

Tags: patch, azure-virtual-machine

What is the reason for an azure vm to become non-compliant after update deployment?

1. Is it because there are any critical or security updates missing?
2. Does having Other updates missing cause a vm to become non-compliant
3. There were no documentation to clarify this, only with the current statistics, I came into this conclusion. If there are any documentation to prove that, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

yes, there may be a chance for missing some critical or security updates.Before you deploy software updates to your machines, review the update compliance assessment results for enabled machines. For each software update, its compliance state is recorded and then after the evaluation is complete, it is collected and forwarded in bulk to Azure Monitor logs.

On a Windows machine, the compliance scan is run every 12 hours by default, and is initiated within 15 minutes of the Log Analytics agent for Windows is restarted. The assessment data is then forwarded to the workspace and refreshes the Updates table. Before and after update installation, an update compliance scan is performed to identify missing updates, but the results are not used to update the assessment data in the table.it is important to review recommendations on how to configure the [windows Update client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/update-management/configure-wuagent)

After reviewing the compliance results, the software update deployment phase is the process of deploying software updates. To install updates, schedule a deployment that aligns with your release schedule and service window.

After the deployment is complete, review the process to determine the success of the update deployment by machine or target group.[Check deployment status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/update-management/deploy-updates#check-deployment-status)

Comment: thanks for your information.. "Does having Other updates missing cause a vm to become non-compliant". Do you see any azure documentation regarding this point? My major problem is whether having other updates missing effects non compliancy?

Comment: it depends on the policy yo u define.Non-compliant — Computers that are missing at least one critical or security update. · Not assessed — The update assessment data has not been received from the computer within the expected timeframe

Comment: computers that are missing any security or critical updates will shown under non compliant and you can use deployment status to check for the vm's which are missing updates .

Comment: Can you provide the source from where you extracted this information.. thanks